# Getting attachment post using wp_get_attachment_link

Tags: attachments

The WordPress codex on [wp_get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link) says you can use the $permalink parameter to link to the page, not the image.  But I would like to link to the post instead.  I'm trying to get a list of images using the following (updated, see answers below):

```
<?php $new_query = new WP_Query('&showposts=1'); ?>
                        <?php while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php $args = array (
                               'post_type' => 'attachment',
                               'numberposts' => 18,
                               'orderby' => 'date',
                               'status' => 'publish',
                               'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                               'parent' => $post->ID
                        ); ?>
                        <?php $attachments = get_posts($args);
                               if ($attachments) {
                                   foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                                       echo '<li>';
                                       echo '<a href=" ' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">';
                                       echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
                                       echo '</a></li>';

                                   }
                               };

                               endwhile;

                               ?>
```

Having trouble getting the images to link to the post.  I'm not sure how to filter this to get the post, not the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you pass third (`$permalink`) parameter as true in `wp_get_attachment_link()` image will link to attachment's page not image itself. You can use `wp_get_attachment_link` filter to change behavior of that parameter, but in this case it simply means overwriting whole function. Instead I would use [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) and [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

**UPDATE**

Maybe `wp_get_attachment_image()` would fit in this situation better. Here's also how your snipped would look like:

```
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
       echo '<li>';
       echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
       echo '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I would, however, like the image to link to the post and not the image page or image.  Sorry if I was confusing in my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I know that, that's why you'll need `get_permalink()`, see update answer.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, if I wanted to pull attachments from a network, what changes would I make to this attachment loop?

Comment: As network you mean WordPress Multi-Site?

Comment: Yes, multisite, thank you.  By the way, what you recommended is resulting in the images pulling nicely, but the images link to one post on the main site in my multisite installation.  I am posting the exact code I used above.  Thanks!

Comment: For pulling images from whole network, you'll need to use `switch_to_blog()` function, but it's expensive function so you should be careful when using it - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog